# How to fix jQuery UI autocomplete/combobox layout?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, layout

I want to use jQuery UI's autocomplete as a combobox, as showed in [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox). But I have trouble getting the layout right. I want the button to be aligned right beside the input. I created a jsfiddle to show the problem: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/timbuethe/CSypd/)

[image: layout problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some relative positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/CSypd/4/

Comment: `top:` helped, the `position:relative` seems to make no difference though.